# OpenMP - Difference between Directives and Constructs

Tags: openmp

This might seem like a silly question, but I'm learning OpenMP and I am slightly confused with the terminology. 
Are Directives and Constructs the same thing? Or is directive an all-encompassing word that includes constructs as well as orphaned directives?

I've seen words like
`PARALLEL Directive` but also `PARALLEL Region Construct`
And in some tutorials `Work Sharing Constructs` are listed under `OpenMP Directives`.

The [Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbc5t5zd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) makes me think that potentially the entire next line is a directive:

```
 #pragma omp directive-name  [clause[ [,] clause]...] new-line
```

Because of the statement, "**Each directive starts with #pragma omp**". And this would imply that the words `parallel` and `for` (and the others) are constructs. Yet, at the same time, in the exact same line above, they put `directive-name` right after the pragma.

If someone could clarify, that would be great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, a **directive** is the OpenMP statement, like

```
#pragma omp for
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel private(th_id) shared(nthreads)
```

A directive may include **clauses**, like the `private` statement above or `schedule(dynamic, CHUNKSIZE)`.

Directives combined with code form a **construct**. That is, a construct is a *pattern* to accomplish something. So a "parallel construct" is a `parallel` directive, its optional clauses, and any code to be executed:

```
#pragma omp parallel
  printf("Hello, world.\n");
```

A "worksharing construct" is a `parallel for` directive followed by the loop's code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = 2 * i;
```

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe what the Microsoft page meant by `directive-name` is simply the name (that belongs to the directive) that goes in the directive -- So the `directive-name` of the PARALLEL Directive is `parallel`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no shame in actually reading the [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf). §1.2.2 is dedicated entirely to the OpenMP terminology. One can find various definitions in it, including:

> **directive** - In C/C++, a `#pragma`, and in Fortran, a comment, that specifies *OpenMP program* behavior. COMMENT: See Section 2.1 on page 22 for a description of OpenMP *directive* syntax.

Section 2.1 on page 22 reads:

> OpenMP directives for C/C++ are specified with the `pragma` preprocessing directive. The syntax of an OpenMP directive is formally specified by the grammar in Appendix C, and informally as follows:
>
> `#pragma omp` *directive-name [clause[ [,] clause]...] new-line*
>
> Each directive starts with `#pragma omp`. The remainder of the directive follows the conventions of the C and C++ standards for compiler directives. In particular, white space can be used before and after the `#`, and sometimes white space must be used to separate the words in a directive. Preprocessing tokens following the `#pragma omp` are subject to macro replacement.
>
> Directives are case-sensitive.
>
> An OpenMP executable directive applies to at most one succeeding statement, which must be a structured block.

Another handy definition:

> **executable directive** - An OpenMP *directive* that is not declarative. That is, it may be placed in an executable context. COMMENT: All *directives* except the `threadprivate` *directive* are *executable directives*.

Then comes the construct, explained in the terms of the previous two:

> **construct** - An OpenMP *executable directive* (and for Fortran, the paired **end** *directive*, if any) and the associated statement, loop or *structured block*, if any, not including the code in any called routines. That is, in the lexical extent of an *executable directive*.

Microsoft's pages simply cite parts of an (much) earlier OpenMP specification.

Comment: Thank you for your addition, Hristo :)